# How to rotate view without any subview inside in iOS project?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a view that holds a picture in it. When I rotate the view using an animation it also rotates all of the content inside (*i.e.* the picture that I'm adding).

Is there a way to unlink them in the storyboard so when I turn the view, only it is the one that turns and not the pictures/buttons that are inside?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a new container view so that the spinner and picture can be siblings instead. The hierarchy would look like.

```
Container View
    Spinner View
    Provider Main Picture
```

Now if you animate the spinner, the picture wont be changed since it's no longer a subview of the spinner.

Comment: so if i add a containerview, and inside the new viewcontroller, i should add the spinnerview, and the provider main picture ? and then spinn the spinner view ?